# How to get all WooCommerce categories and subcategories?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get all woocommerce categories with subcategory but max to third degree, example:

- Main Category
- - First subcategory of Main
- - Second subcategory of Main
- - - First subcategory of Second
- - Third subcategory of Main
- - Fourth subcategory of Main
- - - First subcategory of Fourth
- - - - First subcategory of Fourth's First ------ THIS ONE SHOULD NOT BE DISPLAY!!
- - - - Second subcategory of Fourth's First ------ THIS ONE SHOULD NOT BE DISPLAY!!

```
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'parent'   => 0
    );
    $product_cat = get_terms( $args );
    foreach ($product_cat as $parent_product_cat) {
        echo    '<ul class="nav-menu__cats"><li><a href="'.get_term_link($parent_product_cat->term_id).'">' .$parent_product_cat->name. '</a><ul>';
    $child_args = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'parent'   => $parent_product_cat->term_id
    );
    $child_product_cats = get_terms( $child_args );
    
    foreach ($child_product_cats as $child_product_cat) {
        echo    '<li><a href="'.get_term_link( $child_product_cat->term_id ).'">' .$child_product_cat->name. '</a></li><ul>';
            $child2_args = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'hide_empty' => false,
                    'parent'   => $child_product_cat->term_id
            );
            $child2_product_cats = get_terms( $child2_args );
            foreach ($child2_product_cats as $child2_product_cat) {
                echo    '<li><a href="'.get_term_link( $child2_product_cat->term_id ).'">' .$child2_product_cat->name. '</a></li></ul>';
            }
    }

    echo        '</ul></li></ul>';
    }
```

Above code works but with all subcategories and I need only Main Category->Subcategory of Main->Subcategory of subcategory and thats all.